# How to create Facebook app when I already have a working website

Tags: javascript, facebook, html

I have .XML, .JS and some .JPG files for 3D-pano in HTML5, which are work properly on my site 3d-arriving.ru/fotopanorams/html5.
And now I want to make it possible to view directly on facebook. I have registered as facebook developer and have an account on Heroku. But I can only "cloudly" imagine my steps to realize my 3D-pano application on facebook. I think, it have to be a Page Tab, but what's next?
Is there is an easy way to upload my files to facebook or Heroku, to write little code and to make it work? A? :)
Thanx to all, who will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a website online, you don't need to create new one. Facebook apps are simply websites connected with Facebook. If you want users to do any interaction, like logging in, you have to add login dialog to your website. You tagged this question with JS, so I suggest you to check [JavaScript SDK reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). And whatever you want to do, if you want do set your website as application in Page Tab, read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/).

After creating the app with URL for tab pages configured all you have to do is providing a person with admin role on the page with following URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=URL_OWNED_BY_YOUR_FB_APP
```

After that the person who entered this URL will be able to choose the page that she or he wants to create a tab with this app for. Of course only pages that the person has admin role will be visible. So you will be able to add this to your page, and I will be able to add this to my own page, if I had one.

But you have to think if you really need a page on FB and you want to add this app there. If not, you can simply stay with the [canvas app](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/).

Comment: O, thanx for such quick response. Now I need some months to swallow this info :)

Comment: @ДмитрийСухов As long, as you need basic funtionality, I don't think it will take you so long. :) If that is what you needed, consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).